# SQL Server gives me wrong values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm trying to find out the total clicked on a link, but getting wrong results.

My first query, get total rows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [email]
FROM [BOZTICKETS].[dbo].[Bozzuto25]
```

Gets 203 rows

Second query, get those with value False:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [email]
FROM [BOZTICKETS].[dbo].[Bozzuto25]
WHERE (changes = 'FALSE')
```

Which gets 148 rows

Last query `WHERE changes='TRUE'` gets 61 rows

All together it adds up to 209 rows where it should be 203. Any ideas?

Comment: No, it has not according to [Betteride's law of headline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betteridge's_law_of_headlines)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely, you have some emails (six, probably) that have one or more records with changes TRUE *and also* one or more records with changes FALSE.

Those emails will contribute to all three query results.

If so, you can find them with:

```
 SELECT [email] FROM [Bozzuto25] 
    GROUP BY [email]
    HAVING MAX(changes) <> MIN(changes)
```

Comment: You can use SELECT COUNT(email), COUNT(DISTINCT email) to show you the different counts, which will confirm your findings.

Comment: That would only tell you that some emails have multiple records (which I think the OP already knows), not that there are emails with different values in `changes`.  I've amended my answer with one technique to find the problem emails (assuming my hypothesis about the problem is correct).

Answer (score 0):

You probably have duplicate emails.  But you might also have other values in your changes column. This query will give you a nice summary of your "changes"

```
SELECT changes, count(*) 'count'
FROM [BOZTICKETS].[dbo].[Bozzuto25]
GROUP BY changes
```